# Data not passing through with route in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, routes

I have a application with a table of cars:

This is my code:

**Carcomponent.html**

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let car of allCars; index as carId" \>
          <td [routerLink]="['/cars', carId]">{{car.carId}}</td>
          <td>{{car.brand}}</td>
          <td>{{car.model}}</td>
          <td>{{car.color}}</td>
          <td>{{car.topSpeed }}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have register the route like this:

```
{ path: 'cars/:carId', component: CardetailsComponent }
```

And this is my **CarDetails.ts** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CarVM } from '../viewmodels/car-vm';
import { CarService } from '../services/car.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardetails',
  templateUrl: './cardetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardetails.component.css']
})

export class CardetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  car: any;
  carList: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private carservice: CarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.car = params.get('carId');
    });
  }
  getCarList() {
    this.carList = new CarVM();
    this.carservice.getCarById(this.carList.carId).subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.carList = res.data;
      console.log(this.carList)
    })
  }
}
```

And on my **Cardetails.html** I want to show the selected car like this:

```
<h2>Car Details</h2>
<div *ngIf="car">
  <h3>{{ car.brand }}</h3>
  <h4>{{ car.model }}</h4>
  <p>{{ car.color }}</p>
</div>
```

The routing is working fine and fetching the cars is working. Now I want to select one car and see the **brand, model, color** on the next page. I use a viewmodel for this:

```
export class CarVM {
  CarId: number;
  Brand: string;
  Model: string;
  Color: string;
  TopSpeed: number;
}
```

How can I see the selected car on the next page?

I have followed this tutorial:

https://angular.io/start/routing

Comment: What did you get when console.log  `this.car` variable in CardetailsComponent?

Comment: Is `carId` equal to `index`? If not, try this: `<td [routerLink]="['/cars', car.carId]">{{car.carId}}</td>`

Comment: @shadowman_93 I get **undefined**

Comment: @dallows When I use your solution I get the right carId like this: **http://localhost:4200/cars/445** I still don't get the **brand, model, color**

Comment: In your code you are trying to access the property `445` of `CarVM` class witch does not exist. If `CarVM` is really an array then you should use `this.car = CarVM.find(car => car.carId === params.get('carId'))`

Comment: @Fearcoder if you get **undefined** it means that you can't get **params.get** variable properly. Can you please create stackblitz for us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you seem to be bit confused. In `cardetails` component you want to process `carId` from route parameters and use it to get car details. You can either get them from server, or have the service return already loaded details of all cars.

Let's say we are trying to make it happen getting the first way, it might look like this:

```
import { map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.getCar();
}

private getCar(): void {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('carId')),
    switchMap(carId => {
      return this.carservice.getCarById(carId);
    })
  ).subscribe(
    res => {
      this.car = res;
      console.log('@My car:', this.car);
    }
  );
}
```

First, you'll get the `carId` from `route.paramMap`, map it using rxjs `map`, then use `switchMap` to call you `carservice.getCarById(carId)` and have it return Observable to which you can subscribe. This should do the trick. Don't forget to properly map it/create CarVM object from it.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you don't have CarVM object properly on CardetailsComponent. You are only getting carId into CarVM here: `this.car = CarVM[+params.get('carId')];`

First you need to create CarVM properly with your class variables. And the you can call your index.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { CarVM } from '../viewmodels/car-vm';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cardetails',
  templateUrl: './cardetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cardetails.component.css']
})

export class CardetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  car: any;
  carList: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
          this.car = params.get('carId');
        });
      }
   getCarList(){
   this.carList = new CarVM();
   //call your service here to fill your carList variable and once you get car list, you will be able to access variable using with your index (this.car).
  }
 }
```

Comment: you mean something like this? **CarVM car: any;**

Comment: I have use your solution. I get the carId in the url but not the rest. I gonna make a stackblitz

Comment: I have change it I also use a backend for the data

Comment: I have filled the variable